# I can't get this user form with command button to filter colour

Tags: excel, vba

I build a user form that is trying to filter and Copy rows that are not highlighted  Highlighted/Coloured Cells to Another Excel Worksheet. It manages to copy all the items on the sheet.
It is unable to filter the content that is not highlighted in red, it instead simply copy all items in the worksheet

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-znlrwhy3w
I am trying to do something similar to the video above, but instead, I want to filter out items that aren't highlighted in red.
I want to try my own code instead of using the one in the video.
I want to know what part of my code has problems that is causing it not to filter out items that is not highlighted in red.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sheetcan As Worksheet, iRow1 As Long, iRow2 As Long

Set Newbook1 = Workbooks.Add
Set sheetcan = Newbook1.Worksheets(1)
sheetcan.Name = "Filtered candidate by harry"
'Newbook1.Window(1).Visible = False

For iRow1 = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Rows.Count - 1
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Resize(iRow1, 10).Copy sheetcan.Range("A1") 
    End If
Next iRow1
sheetcan.Columns.AutoFit

'Newbook1.Window(1).Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better to use AutoFilter and you could avoid a loop. In your code you can't check the colour of multiple cells in one go, you have to loop through each.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time on Stack OVerflow so bear with me.

A standard workaround i use for this matter is copying and pasting only visible cells.

We can make a for loop that hides any red rows, pastes, then unhides using

```
    For iRow1 = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).Rows.Count - 1
    If iRow1.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then iRow1.EntireRow.Hidden=True
    Next iRow1
'Copy and paste visible cells
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

NewRange.Paste

'unhide
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").rows.entirerow.hidden=false
```